# Given $n$ integers $a_1$ to $a_n$ and an integer $K$, does there exist a solution which satisfies the following equation?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, linear-diophantine-equations

Given $n$ integers $a_1$ to $a_n$ and an integer $K$, does there exist a solution which satisfies the following equation?

$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i\cdot x_i = K $$

Note that all $x_i$ must need to be NON-NEGATIVE integers.

My Attempt:
This seems to be a NP-hard problem, special kind of Knapsack problem with exact value to match.
I don't have much idea apart from brute force on entire range like a knapsack problem.
Someone told me it can be solved efficiently by graph theory .

Comment: Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem (the classic version requires $x_i\in \{0,1\}$).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: It is an example of the coin change problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change-making_problem

Comment: @Community As usual the comment generated by the Bot misses the mark.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni You mean O(K*log(K)) is the best we can get? Mind you we need not find solutions to the equation , we just need to tell if a solution exists or not. It's a decision problem.

Comment: Having such bounds in the problem description suggests that this might be from Project Euler or CodeChef. IIRC we have a rule not to help people cheat on those, so can you still my fears. Admittedly, more typically they use constants like $10^9+7$ or some such :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen you can search for all live contests.  I couldn't find it anywhere

Comment: Can you give the source of the question? Where did you run into it?

Comment: From a friend. his name is Shohag.

Comment: I think [this](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/1002) is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

The coin problem, also called Frobenius problem, is probably what you are looking for:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem

It is the problem of finding the largest $K$ that is not reachable, given the $a_i$.

For the problem to have a solution, the $a_i$ must have no common divisor greater than 1.

As for finding a solution with a computer:

- As we know that for 2 $a_i$ $x$ and $y$ (EDIT: which are coprime), the largest non-reachable number is $xy - x - y$, if $K$ is greater than this (for the two smallest coprime $a_i$) then the problem is solved positively.
- If not, then a brute force approach may not be too much costly, because the $a_i$ will be roughly greater than $\sqrt K$.

Comment: What if the two smallest $a$s have a non-trivial common divisor? But no common divisors with, say, $a_{17}$? But the link to the coin problem is useful, so +1.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen You are right. Then there could be heuristics such as: if a1 and a2 have d>1 as gcd, and if K[d] is not 0, then we may first use a17 to compensate that K[d]... provided a17 is not too big. Of course the trouble with such heuristics is that they can get you a positive result, but cannot get you a negative one.

Comment: A={2, 4, 7, 9, 15} and K= 37
clearly answer is Yes. But your also says No

Comment: @linasoares I proposed heuristics to get faster a positive result. But if the answer is no it does not mean there is no solution. Anyway there is a large literature when searching for "Frobenius coin problem", that's where to look for a good algorithm.

Comment: In your example the 2 smallest coprime ai are 2 and 7. That makes xy-x-y = 5. K=37 > 5, it shows the problem is feasible.